# Calling a Python class method from C++, if given an initialised class as PyObject

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, c-api

I have a function in c++ that receives a initialised class as a PyObject.
The python class is:

```py
class Expression:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def get_source(self):
        #Check if the object whose source is being obtained is a function.
        if inspect.isfunction(self.obj):
            source = inspect.getsourcelines(self.obj)[0][1:]
            ls = len(source[0]) - len(source[0].lstrip())
            source = [line[ls:] for line in source]
            #get rid of comments from the source
            source = [item for item in source if item.lstrip()[0] != '#']
            source = ''.join(source)
            return source
        else:
            raise Exception("Expression object is not a function.")
```

The c++ receives this:

```py
Expression(somefunctogetsource)
```

From c++ how do I call the get_source method of the expression object?
So far I've read the python c-api docs and tried things like this:

```cpp
PyObject* baseClass = (PyObject*)expression->ob_type;
PyObject* func = PyObject_GetAttrString(baseClass, "get_source");
PyObject* result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(func, expression, NULL);
```

And convert the result to a string, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler than you're making it. You don't need to retrieve anything from the base class directly. Just do:

```
PyObject* result = PyObject_CallMethod(expression, "get_source", NULL);
if (result == NULL) {
    // Exception occurred, return your own failure status here
}
// result is a PyObject* (in this case, it should be a PyUnicode_Object)
```

[`PyObject_CallMethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallMethod) takes an object to call a method of, a C-style string for the method name, and a format string + varargs for the arguments. When no arguments are needed, the format string can be `NULL`.

The resulting `PyObject*` isn't super useful to C++ code (it has runtime determined 1, 2 or 4 byte characters, depending on the ordinals involved, so straight memory copying from it into `std::string` or `std::wstring` won't work), [but `PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize` can be used to get a UTF-8 encoded version and length](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize), which can be used to efficiently construct a `std::string` with equivalent data.

If performance counts, you may want to explicitly make a `PyObject*` representing `"get_source"` during module load, e.g. with a global like:

```
PyObject *get_source_name;
```

which is initialized in the module's `PyMODINIT_FUNC` with:

```
get_source_name = PyUnicode_InternFromString("get_source");
```

Once you have that, you can use the more efficient [`PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs) with:

```
PyObject* result = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(expression, get_source_name, NULL);
```

The savings there are largely in avoiding constructing a Python level `str` from a C `char*` over and over, and by using `PyUnicode_InternFromString` to construct the string, you're using the interned string, making the lookup more efficient (since the name of `get_source` is itself automatically interned when `def`-ed in the interpreter, no actual memory comparison of the contents takes place; it realizes the two strings are both interned, and just checks if they point to the same memory or not).

Comment: Ah wow, I really tried making that more difficult for myself. Thanks for explaining it so well. The extra comments about performance are incredibly useful, much appreciated!

Comment: @Methodicle: Glad I could help. Minor side-note: Pretty sure `[item for item in source if item.lstrip()[0] != '#']` is an accident waiting to happen; it'll die with an `IndexError` if one of the source lines is empty (nothing but whitespace). Change `item.lstrip()[0] != '#'` to `not item.lstrip().startswith('#')` to make it safe (`item.lstrip()[:1] != '#'` would also be safe, but less obvious in intent). I'd also recommend changing your `raise Exception` to `raise TypeError`, since the whole point is that the input was of the incorrect type, and more specific exceptions are more helpful.

Comment: Wow thanks Again, just before I saw your comment It actually died died because of that exact reason. I must need more practice I thought I'd done well thinking about comment lines but completely forgot empty lines.